# GA-Algorithm returning "non-numeric argument to binary operator" when parallel computing

Tags: r, parallel-processing, genetic-algorithm

For some reason the GA algorithm returns "non-numeric argument to binary operator" when I use the option parallel = TRUE. 
The optimization algorithm seems to works without that option or when setting parallel = FALSE.
I have installed all the neccessary packages and they are all up to date. The R Version that I work with is 3.3.2 on a 64Bit machine.

I am basically calling a function within the function that I try to optimize. The code below is a very simple example of the general structure of the problem that returns the same error code.

```
fun_in <- function(a, b, c, d, e)
{
  return(a + b + c + d + e)
}

fun_out <- function(a, b, c, d, e, f, g)
{
 x <- f +g
 y <- fun_in(a = a, b = b, c = c, d = d, e = e)
 z <- x + y
 return(z)
}

library('GA')

a <- 1
b <- 1
c <- 1
d <- 1
e <- 1
f <- 1
g <- 1

fitness <- function(x) -fun_out(a, b, c, d, e, f, g)
lower_bound <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
upper_bound <- c(5,5,5,5,5,5,5)
coef_names <- c('a', 'b', 'b', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g')

GA <- ga(type = "real-valued", 
         fitness = fitness, 
         min = lower_bound, 
         max = upper_bound,
         popSize = 100,
         maxiter = 1000,
         pmutation = 0.8,
         pcrossover = 0.8,
         maxFitness = 1e-5,
         names = coef_names,
         parallel = TRUE
)
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple fix for argument name in fitness()

```
 --- fitness <- function(x) -fun_out(a, b, c, d, e, f, g)
 +++ fitness <- function(x) -fun_out(x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4], x[5], x[6], x[7])
```